# How to create a triangle from DIV

Tags: html

I have a `div` in HTML with some text written in it.
The `div` is created by setting its `X`, `Y` coordinates and `height` and `width`. 
I want to draw a triangle Superimposing that `div` so that my content is not lost.
I cannot change the `X`,`Y` coordinates as my other `div`'s positioning is based on this `div`.
Generating a Triangle using multiple `div`'s approach also does not seem feasible as I am not sure in which `div` I will write my text then......

Can somebody suggest an idea on how I can do this..?

Comment: With a background image? With SVG? With an AJAX-style JavaScript library? With a magic marker? It's hard to say what the best answer would be without more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with an image, but a more interesting way is to mess around with the borders of a div to make a triangle.

```
.triangle {
     font-size: 0px; 
     line-height: 0%; 
     width: 0px;
     border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
     border-left: 10px solid #000;
     border-right: 10px solid #000;
}
```

How this is works explained much more clearly [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for developing triangle:

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    width:0; 
    border-bottom:120px solid red; 
    border-left:60px solid white; 
    border-right:60px solid white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```